# Add Admin menus or submenus depending on conditions

Tags: plugin-development, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

I have two plugins in two different files that add a submenu (the plugin title) to the admin panel like this:

Plugin 1:

```
function myplugin1_setup_submenu(){
    add_submenu_page("mybrand", "My Plugin1", "My Plugin1", 0, "myplugin1", "myPlugin1PageFunction");
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin1_setup_submenu');
```

Plugin 2:

```
function myplugin2_setup_submenu(){
    add_submenu_page("mybrand", "My Plugin2", "My Plugin2", 0, "myplugin2", "myPlugin2PageFunction");
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin2_setup_submenu');
```

There must be, somewhere, a menu which is the brand of these 2 plugins:

```
function mybrand_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Brand', 'My Brand', 'manage_options', 'mybrand', 'myBrandPageFunction' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'mybrand_setup_menu');
```

But this will not suit my needs because what I need to do is this:

- If a single plugin is installed from this brand, I would like this plugin to be a menu (not a submenu) on the admin panel and, in this case, I don't want the brand to appear anywhere.
- But if there are more than one plugin installed from this brand, I would like
  them all to be submenus of the "My Brand" menu.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: First things first: How are you determining whether one or more plugins are installed from "this brand"?

Comment: I believe it is part of the issue. It can be retrieved from the "Author" in the files header or It can be a constant variable I add on each plugin which will contain the brand name or it can be the first argument from "add_submenu_page" which is always the brand slug. I don't know if all or none of these "flags" are usable to detect the plugin as belonging to the brand. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The good news, is that you can do it all in the same hook.

Comment: Your answer is more teasing than helping. Anyway, I found a way to do it. Don't know if it is optimized but at least, it works. Thank you.

Comment: I started to write an answer this morning and got distracted. Let me see if I can find the tab and finish it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution:

File 1:

```
//Count the number of active plugins whose Author is "My Brand", and store the number in a global variable.

    $GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']=0;

    if (!function_exists('get_plugins')){require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';}
    $plugins=get_plugins();

    $activated_plugins=get_option('active_plugins');

    foreach ($activated_plugins as $p){           
        if( (isset($plugins[$p])) AND ($plugins[$p]['Author']=='My Brand')){
            $GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']++;
        }            
    }   

// Add menus on sidebar

    if($GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']<2)
    {
        function sub1_setup_menu()
        {
            add_menu_page('Sub 1','Sub 1','manage_options','sub1','sub1_admin_page');
        }
        add_action('admin_menu','sub1_setup_menu');
    }
    else
    {
        function sub1_setup_menu()
        {
            if (empty($GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']['My Brand'] ) ){
            add_menu_page('My Brand','My Brand','manage_options','mybrand','mybrand1_admin_page');
            }
            add_submenu_page("mybrand","Sub 1","Sub 1",'manage_options',"sub1","sub1_admin_page");
            remove_submenu_page("mybrand","mybrand");
        }
        add_action('admin_menu','sub1_setup_menu');
    }

// Initialize Brand and Plugin Admin Page

    function mybrand1_admin_page()
    {
        echo "<h1>My Brand Plugins</h1>";
    }   

    function sub1_admin_page()
    {
        echo "<h1>Sub 1</h1>";
    }
```

File 2:

```
//Count the number of active plugins whose Author is "My Brand", and store the number in a global variable.

    $GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']=0;

    if (!function_exists('get_plugins')){require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';}
    $plugins=get_plugins();

    $activated_plugins=get_option('active_plugins');

    foreach ($activated_plugins as $p){           
        if( (isset($plugins[$p])) AND ($plugins[$p]['Author']=='My Brand')){
            $GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']++;
        }            
    }   

// Add menus on sidebar

    if($GLOBALS['mybrand_active_plugins']<2)
    {
        function sub2_setup_menu()
        {
            add_menu_page('Sub 2','Sub 2','manage_options','sub2','sub2_admin_page');
        }
        add_action('admin_menu','sub2_setup_menu');
    }
    else
    {
        function sub2_setup_menu()
        {
            if (empty($GLOBALS['admin_page_hooks']['My Brand'])){
            add_menu_page('My Brand','My Brand','manage_options','mybrand','mybrand2_admin_page');
            }
            add_submenu_page("mybrand","Sub 2","Sub 2",'manage_options',"sub2","sub2_admin_page");
            remove_submenu_page("mybrand","mybrand");
        }
        add_action('admin_menu','sub2_setup_menu');
    }

// Initialize Brand and Plugin Admin Page

    function mybrand2_admin_page()
    {
        echo "<h1>My Brand Plugins</h1>";
    }   

    function sub2_admin_page()
    {
        echo "<h1>Sub 2</h1>";
    }
```

I don't know if this can be achieved in a shorter way but it works.